# Can I ControlClick a link or object if there's no Control information?

Tags: automation, autoit

I'm using AutoIt to automate the handling of a proprietary Windows EHR application, and it looks like the creators of the application wrote it without adding classes, IDs, or names to any of their links or menu items inside the application. The application I'm trying to automate is PrimeSUITE by Greenway Health.

I've gotten it to work by using `MouseClick` and adding coordinates, but that only works so long as the user doesn't move the Window. I'd like to use the more reliable `ControlClick` method to send click commands (I don't think there's a third way to send click commands in AutoIt).

Luckily, there's a keyboard shortcut built into the application to open the menu item I want in a new window. This is how I'm currently having to access the menu item:

```
WinActivate(": PrimeSUITE -- #CompanyName# -- PRIMESUITETEST")
Send("{F7}")
WinActivate("Report Selection -- Webpage Dialog")
WinWaitActive("Report Selection -- Webpage Dialog")
```

At this point I have to rely on the window's position on the screen not moving, so that I can send `MouseClick` coordinates (whose origin point begins in the top-left corner of my monitor screen, rather than the current active Window's top-left corner).

I'd *like* to be able to activate it somehow like:

```
ControlClick( ": PrimeSUITE -- #CompanyName# -- PRIMESUITETEST", "Reporting", "[CLASS:Internet Explorer_Server; INSTANCE:1]", "left", 1, 491, 15)
```

So that the coordinates are relative to the active window's top-left corner rather than the monitor screen's top-left corner.

For context, this is what I see when I am hovering in the application's main window (note, the application is run from the desktop; it's not a web app accessed in IE), no matter which part, regardless of whether I'm in a blank space or hovering a link/menu item:

[image]

But as soon as I hover over a menu item and then move the cursor to a submenu item, I get this:

[image]

Here is the Tree View of what Inspect.exe found:

[image: Tree View]

Am I going to be stuck with the `MouseClick` method via screen coordinates, or is there a way to use `ControlClick` or some other way to send clicks programmatically?

Comment: Probably UI Automation API extensions would help here. Is your control visible to Inspect.exe?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Took me a while to find Inspect.exe; I've never used it before. I've added a screenshot of its findings on the control to my post above.

Comment: It would be better to see the controls hierarchy. But I can take a look later when I have a chance. Is it Win8.1 or Win10?

Comment: BTW, you need to set `UIAccess="true"` in the Application Manifest File (for the client app) as it referenced in [the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ee671610(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Neither; it's Windows 7. By controls hierarchy, do you mean the left side of the inspect window instead of the right?

Comment: Also, I don't have access to the source code of the PrimeSUITE application.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the left side (tree view) of the Inspect.exe for PrimeSUITE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it is a desktop application it is using IE objects. You can attach to it with [_IEAttach](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IEAttach.htm) and then use [_IEAction](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IEAction.htm) to click on objects like your menu.

Here is an example of how to attach to PrimeSUITE (you may need to change the window title).

```
#include <IE.au3>

$hWin = WinGetHandle("PrimeSUITE")

If WinExists($hWin) Then

    $oIE = _IEAttach($hWin, "embedded")

    _IELoadWait($oIE)

    MsgBox(262144, "", _IEBodyReadHTML($oIE))
Else
    MsgBox(262144, "", "Window not found.")
EndIf
```

Once you are attached you can look at the HTML to see how you want to automate the program. You have a lot of IE functions besides _IEAttach that you can use. For example: _IELinkClickByText, _IELinkClickByIndex, _IEFormElementSetValue, and _IEFormElementOptionSelect.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this tomorrow at work. I had some suspicions when the "run" location for the application led to a filepath and IP address; it seems to be a sort of bridge between a true desktop app and a web app.

Comment: Trying this with the full PrimeSUITE window name gave me a MsgBox saying "0", so I'm not sure I will be able to attach to it.

Comment: I am 99% sure you can attach to it. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Oh, yes... I had that minimized first run. Line 1:  `--> IE.au3 T3.0-2 Error from function _IEPropertyGet, $_IESTATUS_InvalidObjectType` Line 2:
`--> IE.au3 T3.0-2 Warning from function _IEAttach, $_IESTATUS_NoMatch` Line 3: `--> IE.au3 T3.0-2 Error from function _IELoadWait, $_IESTATUS_InvalidDataType` Line 4: `--> IE.au3 T3.0-2 Error from function _IEBodyReadHTML, $_IESTATUS_InvalidDataType"`

Comment: Nope; I'm getting the Window Not Found MsgBox

Comment: The console output was `+>12:02:07 AutoIt3.exe ended.rc:0 +>12:02:07 AutoIt3Wrapper Finished.   >Exit code: 0    Time: 2.365` for the second version. and the same for the third/latest version.

Comment: If you are getting the Window Not Found MsgBox then the window title you are using is not right. Copy it form the AutoIt Info Tool so you know it is right. Once we know that is right we can check to see if the rest of the code is working.

Comment: You're right, when copying it I forgot to replace PrimeSUITE with the full window name. The second rev of the answer gave me a 0 but the third one is working. It pops up a MsgBox with the body HTML, though I'll need to output it to something else so that I can see it all/copy it.

Comment: I am happy it is working for you. I added a few more notes to the answer about how you can automate it now.